# How can I get the first number of a line in this table with regex?

Tags: regex, gitlab

GitLab gives an option to have a badge represent your current code coverage. It does this by looking at the output of some CI script, then runs regex over the output.

With that being said, given an output like this:

```
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File               |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files          |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
 actions/flight    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  filter.js        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 components/Button |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
  Button.jsx       |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
 components/Toggle |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
  Toggle.jsx       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

I would like to be able to get the value of `All files:% Stmts` (which should be 100 in this case).

Currently I'm working with this regex, but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
/^All files\s*\|\s*(\d*)/
```

Comment: Did you put the regex in multiline mode, so that `^` would match the beginning of the line instead of the beginning of the string? Try removing the `^`. [Your regex works in multiline mode](https://regex101.com/r/zZ6uT1/1).

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to do the trick:" mean? What result does it give you? How is that different to what you want? How do you use the outcome of that regex? Is that maybe where your problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue configuring our GitLab instance for code coverage reporting with Jest. It seems like it works in global mode, so the multiline solution is indeed not going to work, like @4castle suggested.

The regex we ended up using is the following, it also matches floats:

```
/All files\s*\|\s*([\d.]+)/
```